# Visible Headless Chrome Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, memory, multiprocessing

I am writing a program that opens 15 Chrome Selenium instances using `multiprocessing` module. Each session refreshes itself and extracts some text every five seconds. Here is the code :

```
import os
import time
import multiprocessing
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager





def driver_routine(url, file_session):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();

    chrome_options.add_argument(r'--user-data-dir=' + os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '\\' + file_session + '\\selenium')
 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = chrome_options)
    
            
    while True:
        driver.get(url)
        text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//body')
        time.sleep(5)




if __name__=='__main__':
    processes = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
    url = 'https://somesite.com/'

    for i in range(len(processes)):
        file_session = 'session-' + str(i)
        processes[i] = multiprocessing.Process(target=driver_routine, args=(url, file_session,))
        processes[i].start()
```

The issue is that it fills up my CPU memory (from task manager) to 100%, making my PC work very slow. I figured that adding these two lines in the `driver_routine` function:

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
```

will decrease the CPU memory usage. So that kind of fixed my issue. But now the problem is that I can't see the browser instances. Is there any way to satisfy both of my issues? I was thinking maybe starting the browser in `--headless` mode and reopening its GUI form (somehow) whenever I feel the need, that would be awesome. Or maybe a work around regarding the memory usage issue. I am a beginner in python and still learning. Any help is appreciated.